# R: Get 2 variable values to occupy single cell separated by new line

Tags: r, dataframe, bind, paste

I am trying to get 2 variable values to populate 1 cell.

As an example, say I have the following data:

```
var1 <- c("100","200","300","400")
var2 <- c("800","900","1,000","800")
var1andVar2 <- paste(var1,var2, sep = "\n")

var3 <- c("11","22","33","44")

allVars <- rbind(var1andVar2,var3)
```

This code gets me the following output:

```
> allVars
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]         [,4]      
   var1andVar2 "100\n800" "200\n900" "300\n1,000" "400\n800"
   var3        "11"       "22"       "33"         "44"
```

However I am trying to get this as an output:

```
> allVars
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]         [,4]      
   var1andVar2 "100"      "200"      "300"        "400"
               "800"      "900"      "1,000"      "800"
   var3        "11"       "22"       "33"         "44"
```

So my var1 and var2 are occupying a single cell together with them separated by a new line.

Any ideas how to achieve this?? I appreciate it!!

Comment: Maybe try importing `library(gsubfn)` then `strapply(allVars$var1andVar2, "\n", as.character, simplify = c)`

Comment: AFAIK I don't think you could have two values in a single cell. It is called a "cell" for a reason. Why don't you try putting them in a list `list(var1 = ...` and store that list in the cell?

Comment: This is a question of how your object (and the strings inside) is printed in the console. Most likely you are trying to achieve something that would be better suited to a different data-structure or output-format. What will happen to your matrix afterwards?

Comment: @JannikBuhr I'm putting it into the datatable package DT. There is no way to merge cells in DT that I know of so I'm trying to get around it. I need my far left column to be the major category, then within each major category the 2 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the options that Datatable (DT) provides and there seems to be a grouping option for rows, howver I am not versed enough in javascript to correctly implement this. If you want to stick with DT, check out this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

However, I found a maybe more elegant solution using the printing options from `kableExtra` that will work in html (shiny) and also pdf-outputs:
see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#group_rows_via_multi-row_cell) for more information.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

var1 <- c("100","200","300","400")
var2 <- c("800","900","1,000","800")
var3 <- c("11","22","33","44")

allVars <- rbind(var1, var2 ,var3)

df <- allVars %>% as.tibble(rownames = "Vars")
df <- df %>% mutate(
    Vars = case_when(
        Vars %in% c("var1","var2") ~ "Var1andVar2",
        TRUE  ~ Vars
    )
)

kable(df) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top")
```

I ran this code in a R-mardown notebook and quite like the output

[image]

It should also work in a Shiny-App.

Comment: does kableExtra have the ability for a user to click a button to instantly print/download to pdf? That is mostly why I am using the DT package in my app

Comment: Yes, see here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html
You can put anything into that downloadable report either as pdf or html that you can put into a markdown document.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a matrix `m` and data frame `d` whose first row contains `var1` and `var2` and the second row contains `var3`.

```
m <- rbind(Map(c, var1, var2), as.list(var3))
d <- as.data.frame(m)
colnames(d) <- 1:ncol(d) # use numbers for column names
```

giving:

```
> d
         1        2          3        4
1 100, 800 200, 900 300, 1,000 400, 800
2       11       22         33       44

> d[[1,1]][2]
[1] "800"
```

### Update

Revised.